# How to share access 2016 database with multiple user

Tags: database, ms-access, sharing

I migrated my access 97 databases to access 2016 & want to share the database with multiple users having READ/WRITE simultaneously. I kept MS Access 2016 in shared mode and my database in NTFS shared folder in my network.

Even Access is in shared mode  when one user is trying to save their changes i am getting this error

Microsoft Acess can't save design changes or to save to a new database object because another user has the file open. To save your design changes or to save to a new object, You must have exclusive access to the file

Suggest me how can i share the database

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure being shared means you can save changes to data, but not design.

Comment: _"when one user is trying to save their changes"_ What kind of changes, precisely?

Comment: As a general rule multiple users can update data, but any version of Access after 97 does not allow multiple users to modify the code and forms/reports at the same time. So that ability was lost after Access 97 (that is OVER 20 years ago!). Your company been installing every other software application on EACH workstation and you need to do the same with the software you creating with Access. You need to split your database. And you should compile to a mde, or now a accDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Development/Design cannot be shared on the same file. There are steps that need to be done to accomplish this if you have more then 1 developer.

If you are having multiple users update data in the database, split your database using the Database tools > Access Database (Under Move Data tab). This will ask you where you want to save the backend of your file. Choose the file path where you want to save the file.

Take the front end and either email to all your users, or place in a folder location on the share drive for everyone to copy the front end to their desktops.